# How to handle id element when mapping mongoDB document to C# class

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, bson

I want to deserialize document which looks like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("58e67bd8df79507aa3f8a6b6"), 
    "value" : 10,
    "stack" : [
        {
            "id" : "49ccbadf-5964-11e6-b1e9-549f3520935c", 
            "value" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "49ccb5cc-5964-11e6-b1e9-549f3520935c", 
            "value" : 0
        }
    ]
}
```

to a C# class. The class name is Entry and its definition looks like this:

```
public class Entry
{
    public BsonObjectId _id { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
    public List<Stack> stack { get; set; }
}
```

and the Stack class looks like this

```
public class Stack
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
}
```

When querying I get the following exception

```
'An error occurred while deserializing the stack property of class ConsoleApp4.Entry: Element 'id' does not match any field or property of class ConsoleApp4.Stack.'
```

I can decorate the stack class with [BsonIgnoreExtraElements] attribute and then the exception is gone but I don't want to do this since I have to use the id property in querying. Anyone has any idea what I should do? I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

Got it by doing through some trial and error - enough to decorate the stack class with [BsonNoId] attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you need that either. Just change the type like this:

```
public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the ObjectId class you need to pull in the nuget package MongoDB.Bson this will allow you to map the _id property